# When would == be overridden in a different way to .equals?

Tags: c#, equality

I understand the difference between == and .equals.  There are plenty of other questions on here that explain the difference in detail e.g. this one: [What is the difference between .Equals and ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772953/what-is-the-difference-between-equals-and) this one: [Bitwise equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200856/bitwise-equality) amongst many others.

My question is: why have them both (I realise there must be a very good reason) - they both appear to do the same thing (unless overridden differently).

When would == be overloaded in a different way to how .equals is overridden?

Comment: Terminology note: `==` is *never* overridden. It's overloaded.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett , I don't understand.  Could you clarify what you mean.

Comment: They should never have different implementations.

Comment: @Amy, when why have them both (I realise there must be a very good reason)?

Comment: @w0051977 I was humorously suggesting you should automatically fire anybody who overloads the two differently, by which I meant to imply that it's an exceedingly bad idea.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> My question is: why have them both (I realise there must be a very good reason)

If there's a good reason it has yet to be explained to me. Equality comparisons in C# are a godawful mess, and were #9 on my list of things I regret about the design of C#:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2425867

Mathematically, equality is the simplest equivalence relation and it should obey the rules: `x == x` should always be true, `x == y` should always be the same as `y == x`, `x == y` and `x != y` should always be opposite valued, if `x == y` and `y == z` are true then `x == z` must be true.  C#'s `==` and `Equals` mechanisms guarantee *none* of these properties! (Though, thankfully, `ReferenceEquals` guarantees all of them.)

As Jon notes in his answer, `==` is dispatched based on the compile-time types of both operands, and `.Equals(object)` and `.Equals(T)` from `IEquatable<T>` are dispatched based on the runtime type of the left operand.  Why are *either* of those dispatch mechanisms correct?  Equality is not a predicate that favours its left hand side, so why should some but not all of the implementations do so?

Really what we want for user-defined equality is a multimethod, where the runtime types of both operands have equal weight, but that's not a concept that exists in C#.

Worse, it is incredibly common that `Equals` and `==` are given different semantics -- usually that one is reference equality and the other is value equality. There is no reason by which the naive developer would know which was which, or that they were different.  This is a considerable source of bugs. And it only gets worse when you realize that GetHashCode and Equals must agree, but `==` need not.

Were I designing a new language from scratch, and I for some crazy reason wanted operator overloading -- which I don't -- then I would design a system that would be much, much more straightforward. Something like: if you implement `IComparable<T>` on a type then you automatically get `<`, `<=`, `==`, `!=`, and so on, operators defined for you, and they are implemented so that they are consistent.  That is `x<=y` must have the semantics of `x<y || x==y` and also the semantics of `!(x>y)`, and that `x == y` is always the same as `y == x`, and so on.

Now, if your question really is:

> How on earth did we get into this godawful mess?

Then I wrote down some thoughts on that back in 2009:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/09/double-your-dispatch-double-your-fun/

The TLDR is: framework designers and language designers have different goals and different constraints, and they sometimes do not take those factors into account in their designs in order to ensure a consistent, logical experience across the platform.  It's a failure of the design process.

> When would == be overloaded in a different way to how .equals is overridden?

I would never do so unless I had a very unusual, very good reason.  When I implement arithmetic types I always implement all of the operators to be consistent with each other.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess Iequality.Equals should never return a different result to Object.Equals as well?

Comment: @w0051977: That would certainly violate the principle of least surprise.

Comment: @EricLippert, can I just clarify that you are saying that the principle of least surprise is violated by implementing IEquatable.Equals in a different way to Object.Equals?

Comment: @w0051977: Right, it would be surprising if two methods both called Equals returned different results on the same object.

Answer (score 35):

`==` is bound statically, at compile-time, because operators are always static. You overload operators - you can't override them. `Equals(object)` is executed polymorphically, because it's overridden.

In terms of when you'd want them to be different...

Often reference types will override `Equals` but not overload `==` at all. It can be useful to easily tell the difference between "these two references refer to the same object" and "these two references refer to equal objects". (You can use `ReferenceEquals` if necessary, of course - and as Eric points out in comments, that's clearer.) You want to be *really* clear about when you do that, mind you.

`double` has this behavior for NaN values; `==(double, double)` will always return false when either operand is `NaN`, even if they're the same NaN. `Equals` can't do that without invalidating its contract. ([Admittedly `GetHashCode` is broken for different `NaN` values, but that's a different matter](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/6237)...)

I can't remember ever implementing them to give different results, personally.

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for the first paragraph.  Can you explain a scenario or business problem where it is useful to know if: "these two references refer to the same object and these two references refer to equal objects".

Comment: @w0051977: Well for one thing, if two values refer to the same object, they'll *always* be equal. If they refer to different objects that happen to be equal at the moment, if the type is mutable, they may not be equal in the future. You need to know which of those you're interested in.

Comment: In my own code, if I mean reference equals and there is *any* chance that it could be confused with value equality then I call `ReferenceEquals`.  That way it is extremely obvious to the reader / maintainer of the code what I intended.

Answer (score 0):

One case that can come up is when you have a previous codebase that depends on reference equality via `==`, but you decide you want to add value equality checking.  One way to do this is to implement `IEquatable<T>`, which is great, but now what about all that existing code that was assuming only references were equal?  Should the inherited `Object.Equals` be different from how `IEquatable<T>.Equals` works?  This doesn't have an easy answer, as ideally you want all of those functions/operators to act in a consistent way.

For a concrete case in the BCL where this happened, look at [TimeZoneInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218735/unexpected-behavior-in-c-sharp-generic-method-on-equals).  In that particular case, `==` and `Object.Equals` were kept the same, but it's not clear-cut that this was the best choice.

---

As an aside, one way you can mitigate the above problem is to make the class immutable.  In this case, code is less likely be broken by having previously relied on reference equality, since you can't mutate the instance via a reference and invalidate an equality that was previously checked.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you want them to do the same thing, particularly if your code is going to be used by anyone other than yourself and the person next to you. Ideally, for anyone who uses your code, you want to adhere to the principle of least surprise, which having randomly different behaviours violates. Having said this:

Overloading equality is generally a bad idea, unless a type is immutable, and sealed. If you're at the stage where you have to ask questions about it, then the odds of getting it right in any other case are slim. There are lots of reasons for this:

A. Equals and GetHashCode play together to enable dictionaries and hash sets to work - if you have an inconsistent implementation (or if the hash code changes over time) then one of the following can occur:

- Dictionaries/sets start performing as effectively linear-time lookups.
- Items get lost in dictionaries/sets

B. What were you really trying to do? Generally, the identity of an object in an object-oriented language IS it's reference. So having two equal objects with different references is just a waste of memory. There was probably no need to create a duplicate in the first place.

C. What you often find when you start implementing equality for objects is that you're looking for a definition of equality that is "for a particular purpose". This makes it a really bad idea to burn your one-and-only Equals for this - much better to define different EqualityComparers for the uses.

D. As others have pointed out, you overload operators but override methods. This means that unless the operators call the methods, horribly amusing and inconsistent results occur when someone tries to use == and finds the wrong (unexpected) method gets called at the wrong level of the hierarchy.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by: "Overloading equality is generally a bad idea".  If you are using Domain Driven Design (which I realise is beyond the scope of this question), then there are different types of equality.

Comment: So in that terminology, a value object should be immutable, at which point, go ahead (that was one of my exceptions). An entity is defined by its unique identity, and different entities aren't the same even if they have the same attributes. For example, a Tiger with mass = 343.2 kg isn't the same tiger as a different one with the same mass.

Comment: just to be clear you are saying override .equals for entities and value objects?

Comment: Override only for value objects, which should be implemented as immutable. For entities different equalities are a "view of equality for a specific purpose" and not true equality which the language provides via the uniqueness of reference.

Comment: Entities have identity equality.  Surely you have to override them? Like here: https://github.com/vkhorikov/DddInAction/blob/master/DddInPractice.Logic/Common/Entity.cs

Comment: No, absolutely not. You need to ensure instead that you always get the same entity for the same thing. So if there is one Id in the database for something, there is exactly one representation of it in your program's memory. This is by far the best way of proceeding. Entities are mutable - what happens if you change two different tigers, in different ways, that happen to be the same tiger?