# Why is .Equals() dispatched dynamically and == dispatched statically?

Tags: c#

I asked this question recently: [When would == be overridden in a different way to .equals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120905/when-would-be-overridden-in-a-different-way-to-equals).  I was referred to this article: https://ericlippert.com/2013/10/07/math-from-scratch-part-six-comparisons/

I don't fully understand the reference to static method calls (`==` and `!=`) and dynamic method calls (`.Equals()`).  Please see the code below:

```
public class A
{
    private string Field1;
    private string Field2;

    public A(string field1, string field2)
    {
        Field1 = field1;
        Field2 = field2;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(A a1, A a2)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static bool operator !=(A a1, A a2b)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    private string Field3;
    private string Field4;

    public B(string field1, string field2, string field3, string field4)
        : base(field1, field2)
    {
        Field3 = field3;
        Field4 = field4;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(B a1, B a2)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static bool operator !=(B a1, B a2b)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and the test below:

```
A a1 = new B("hello","hello","hello","hello");
A a2 = new B("hello", "hello", "hello", "hello");
var test1 = a1.Equals(a2);
var test2 = a1 == a2;
```

I do not understand the reason it is implemented this way? I have spent the last hour this evening Googling this, however I am still not clear and hence the reason for the question.  Why is `.Equals()` dispatched dynamically and `==` dispatched statically?

Answer (score 7):

`.Equals()` is a virtual instance method, which is subject to normal overriding rules / polymorphism.

`==` is syntactic sugar for the static `.op_Equality()` method, which is a normal static method call with two parameters and therefore does no dynamic dispatch at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "syntactic sugar"? I realise it is also stated like this in the article I posted.  +1.

Comment: Thanks.  I should of seen that when I searched.  Sorry.  Also what do you mean by: .op_Equals()

Comment: @w0051977: Oops; that should be `op_Equality`.  Overloaded operators are syntactic sugar for static methods with names like that.  You can see this in stack traces, decompilers, or Reflection.